# WP7 Linq To SQL(SQL CE) IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7

What is the best practice for implementing `IDataErrorInfo` for an entity class. A class that is associated with a table or view.

I have a View that binds to a record from a Task entity class and need to validate the data before it is saved to the SQL CE database. Need to know the best way to implement `IDataErrorInfo` in this case. I assume just do it on the Task entity class, but want to make sure. Since I have many entity classes that will need validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using autogenerated entities? In such case the usual practice is creating second file in the same project where entity is defined and create its second partial part:

```
public partial Task : IDataErrorInfo
{
    ...
}
```

The reason why the interface is implemented in another partial part is that the initial part is autogenerated by some API (Linq-to-sql, EF, etc) and that API can regenerate the code each time you do some changes. That regeneration would delete your changes but if you place them to your own partial part changes will not be deleted.